# How to see indy tcpserver's progress when sending a stream

Tags: delphi, indy10, tcpserver

In a client using OnWork events:

```
Speed := (count / (stoptick -starttick ))/1024; //in mb
```

I can easily determine the progress.  But on the server side .. how can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

The exact same way - using the `OnWork` events.  You just have to assign the event handlers manually in code, such as in the server's `OnConnect` event, or just whenever you are reading streams:

```
AContext.Connection.OnWorkBegin := MyWorkBeginHandler; 
AContext.Connection.OnWork := MyWorkHandler;
AContext.Connection.OnWorkEnd := MyWorkEndHandler;
```

Comment: I should have noticed that.. thanks man.. once again you save my day